# Apache Camel: Why I can't send bean text to jms

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel

I have very simple pojo class:

```
public class MessageBean {

    String text;

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return text;
    }

}
```

And camel route:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        final MessageBean bean = new MessageBean();
        bean.text = "This is the text";

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        ConnectionFactory conFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://127.0.0.1:61616");

        context.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(conFactory));

        try {
            context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {

                    from("direct:hello").process(new Processor() {

                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                            exchange.getIn().setBody(bean);
                        }
                    }).setBody(simple("${body.message}")).to("jms:queue:Test.Queue");
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            context.start();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            context.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I don't understand why I can not send text from bean variable `text` to activemq queue??

When I try to send from folder the txt file it sends correctly to the queue in jms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a message into a camel route, you need to send it to an endpoint that is a consumer in your route, in this case, `direct:start`. The easiest way to do this here is to use `ProducerTemplate`. After your context has been started:

```
 ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
 template.sendBody("direct:start", bean);
```

Although if you ultimately just want to send the contents of `bean.getMessage()` to your JMS queue (that's what it looks like you're trying to do here), you could just do this instead and remove the `setBody()` call from your route:

```
 template.sendBody("direct:start", bean.getMessage());
```

[More information on ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html)

Comment: You just need to kick the route by using ProducerTemplate to send a message (it could even be an empty message).